# What is the difference between Simple REST implementation with Spring REST controller and with Spring Integration over HTTP inbound adapters?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

We can take library implementation as an example. Straightway I will use REST design , will expose REST api over http and client can make REST call with the URI. To implement this, we use Spring Rest Controller. Someone might use Spring Integration over HTTP with inbound adapters. Definitely this approach is cumbersome than the previous one with little complexity of handling Messaging xml configurations etc. I would like to know when to use what or which is better? Why we go for spring integration? It would be great if someone could point me in right direction ?

Thanks,
Amritendu

Answer (score 1):

It's a design decision.

Use Spring Integration if you have other messaging operations in your application (e.g. interacting with other remote services, brokers etc). Or, if you want loosely coupled components in your application that don't have direct knowledge of other components, interfaces etc.

In other words, if your application is based on [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), use Spring Integration.

If you are simply invoking regular java code (service layer beans, repositories), and want to write everything yourself, just use a REST controller directly.